# Trying to run a C program on Unix but a little confused with how input file is handled

Tags: c, shell, unix, input

I'm trying to run a C program in a Unix environment and I have an input file as well. The teacher said we can run it by typing in

```
gcc programName ./a.out inputFile
```

or

```
gcc programName ./a.out inputFile > viewFile
```

My question is: how is this handled within the C program? Like, is the input file being added as a parameter for `main` (or like its name or something) or is it acting like it's reading from `system.in` or something else?

I'm getting a message saying that there's an error opening the input file and I have `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`. If someone could explain what's going on and how the input file is handled, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: "I'm having trouble figuring how to phrase my question so I figured I'd just ask here." -> **Bad idea**. Questions that have a clear problem statement are  well received here. That said: when you run your compiled program as `./a.out inputfile` then `argc == 2` and `argv[1]` will be equal to the C string `"inputfile"`

Comment: When running `./a.out inputfile`, any output to `stdout` will be shown on the terminal you use. When running `./a.out inputfile > viewfile` then that output won't be shown but instead written to a file `viewfile` (will be created or its contents overwritten if there's already a file with that name). This is known as output redirection and implemented in the shell you're using, thus separate from your program.

Comment: @Daniel Jour Ok I think that clears some things up for me. Thanks

Comment: Finally, if you want to stick to pure `stdin` / `stdout` based IO for a start, then you can also redirect the input of your program (so that you don't have to type it in every time) to read from a file: `./a.out < inputfile > viewfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your professor mentions two ways of calling the file:

1. `./a.out inputFile`
2. `./a.out inputFile > viewFile`

For both forms:

- `argc` would be `2`.
- `argv[0]` would be a string representing the program name,
- `argv[1]` would be `"inputFile"`.

POSIX shells interpret `> filename` to mean redirecting the program's output (specifically stdout) to the given filename.

Command redirections do not appear in the list of arguments from the program's perspective (although there are usually system-specific ways of finding the original command line out).

Answer (score 0):

First off, `gcc programName.c` is a separate command.

`./a.out inputFile` calls your `main` function with `argc = 2` and `argv = { "./a.out", "inputFile", NULL }`. (The shell splits the command line into words, then treats the first word as the name of a program and calls it with all arguments.)

`./a.out inputFile > viewFile` passes the same arguments to `main` as the example above. The difference is that `> viewFile` instructs the shell to open (and clobber/create) a `viewFile` file and redirect `stdout` to it before running the program. In other words, your program only sees `./a.out` and `inputFile` as arguments, but everything written to `stdout` ends up in `viewFile`.